# parsing duplicate tags in xml javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I wrote the code below to basically get the data from 'point' and print it, so if I select the tagname 'point' it is printing all the coordinates in the  tag.

But I want to parse through each 'points' tag in a for loop such that the first iteration of the loop prints the all the coordinates in  from first 'points' tag and second iteration prints the coordinates  from second 'points' tag and so on,

and I wrote the code accordingly but it is not consoling anything,I even tried .eq() and nth child but the problem is I have multiple 'points' tag

...

```
 <object>
        <coordinate>pixel</coordinate>
        <type>rectangle</type>
        <description>None</description>
        <possibleresult>
            <name>Intersection</name>
        </possibleresult>
        <points>
            <point>684.999939,182.999985</point>
            <point>682.568420,217.040604</point>
            <point>612.568420,212.040604</point>
        </points>
    </object>
```

...

...

```
 fetch("file.xml")
 .then(response => response.text())
 .then(data => {
   var txt;
   txt="";
   const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
  console.log(xml);
  x = xml.getElementsByTagName("points point");
  for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {

 txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+ "\n";
}
 console.log(txt.split("\n")[0]); //prints the first point tag
console.log(txt);
// $(document).ready(function(){
//var x= $("point:nth-child(1)").text();

console.log(x);
});

})
 .catch(console.error);
```

...

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` expects a Tag name as Argument, not a Css selector. Ie. use `x = xml.getElementsByTagName("point")`.

Comment: if i use getElementsByTagNamw("point") it is printing all the coordinates from the point tag but I want to iterate through "points" and display "point" tags under that points tag only

Comment: Search for `points` then, and for each element found search the `point`descendants, processing the result in whatever way you wish. Your code would include all `points` so there is no material difference, anyway nested looping should get yuo started: `a_ps = xml.getElementsByTagName("points"); for (i = 0; i< a_ps.length; i++) { a_p = a_ps[i].getElementsByTagName("point"); for (j = 0; j<  a_p.length; j++) { /* Whatever */ } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseFromString` returns instance of [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)
where you can use provided functions to get all children in various ways.

Here's a POC:

```js
const data = "<root><object><coordinate>pixel</coordinate><type>rectangle</type><description>None</description><possibleresult><name>Intersection</name></possibleresult><points><point>684.999939,182.999985</point><point>682.568420,217.040604</point><point>612.568420,212.040604</point><point>614.999939,177.999985</point><point>684.999939,182.999985</point></points></object><object><coordinate>pixel</coordinate><type>rectangle</type><description>None</description><possibleresult><name>Small Car</name></possibleresult><points><point>1.000008,267.000000</point><point>-8.266037,257.072083</point><point>-0.000004,249.357117</point><point>9.266041,259.285034</point><point>1.000008,267.000000</point></points></object><object><coordinate>pixel</coordinate><type>rectangle</type><description>None</description><possibleresult><name>Small Car</name></possibleresult><points><point>267.000000,228.000000</point><point>244.000000,232.000000</point><point>241.944946,220.183472</point><point>264.944946,216.183472</point><point>267.000000,228.000000</point></points></object><object><coordinate>pixel</coordinate><type>rectangle</type><description>None</description><possibleresult><name>Small Car</name></possibleresult><points><point>480.591736,217.018555</point><point>458.591736,218.018555</point><point>458.000000,205.000000</point><point>480.000000,204.000000</point><point>480.591736,217.018555</point></points></object></root>";


const parser = new DOMParser();
const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');

for(let objectTag of xml.querySelectorAll('root>object')) {
  console.log(`=== name: ${objectTag.querySelector('name').textContent} ===`)
  for(let x of objectTag.getElementsByTagName('point')) {
   console.log(x.textContent)
 }
}
```